# Issues using session storage with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, session, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to pass a variable from one page to another with JQM. I want to do this using HTML5's sessions.

On my first page I have set up:

```
if(tagslistedarr[i].indexOf('#') == 0){

           arr.push(tagslistedarr[i]);

           var taglink = "<a class='atags' data-role='button' href='photostreamtags.html' onclick='sessionStorage.tag=" + tagslistedarr[i] + "'>" + tagslistedarr[i] + "</a>";

             thisholder.find('.hashtags').append(taglink);
};
```

Which simply takes a #hashtag strong from an array and turns it into a link, with the hashtag strong being the variable I want to send.

On the recieving page, I have set up simply:

```
    alert('Tag: ' + sessionStorage.tag);
```

But this doesnt work - nothing come through.

The `.append()` works and the link redirects to the correct page, but I dont get the alert appearing - the variable doesnt appear to be saving or being retrieved.

Both of these scripts are positioned correctly within the JQM `data-role="page"` element and are wrapped in:

```
$( "#photostreampage" ).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {
});
```

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I think your script is not proper  where you open  this "<"  so you can close "'>" and second thing when you click on <a> tag your page redirect before your onclick call

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the way you set and retrieve your `sessionStorage` object.

```
//Setting your sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('tag', tagslistedarr[i]);

//Retrieving your sessionStorage
sessionStorage.getItem('tag');
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Raoul suggestion, make sure storage is applicable in your browser:

```
If (('sessionStorage' in window) && window['sessionStorage'] !== null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('tag', yourvalue);
});
```

similar validation when you get the value. Wrap that in a function and call it from the onClick event.